# get the closest textbox in same table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following controls in the same table.

```
<td>
     <asp:TextBox ID="tbOwnerSearchField" Text="Search..." ClientIDMode="Static"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>

<td>
     <input type="button" id="btnSearch" data-field="tbOwnerSearchField" value="Search" />
</td>
```

I currently use a data attribute of the button element to store the textbox id like this:

```
data-field="tbOwnerSearchField"
```

I then reference that textbox in my jQuery methods like this:

```
var searchField = $(this).data("field");
var searchTerm = $("#" + searchField).val();
```

To me, my code seems convoluted...Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Looks good to me. I dont think its convoluted, your are keeping how the controls work inside the html, and then building them out in the javascript.  I'm a fan of this design.

Comment: I was concerned by this mostly: "#" + searchField...it looks bad in my eyes but I can't figure out how to get around it

Comment: I see what your saying. Something to strongly bind the control without doing the jquery lookup for the second dom element.

Comment: I dont think this is an answer, but what if you instead did a data-link='searchowner'  on all elements (this case button and text) that were related. Then add another element data-action='search' on the button.  Running a script onload would group all data-link attribues together, and bind the action element to that group. Now you would know how each control relates.  Sounds more convoluted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put Textbox and input in a single td element like :

```
<td>
     <asp:TextBox ID="tbOwnerSearchField" Text="Search..." ClientIDMode="Static"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <input type="button" id="btnSearch" data-field="tbOwnerSearchField" value="Search" />
</td>
```

and than you can do :

```
var TxtValue = $(this).siblings().eq(0).val();
```

Comment: My only concern would be when you forget to wrap your shit! Stuff breaks down